# How to maintain a single instance of request queu across my entire application

Tags: android, android-volley

I think I am having trouble with the "object orientedness" of Java

So here I have a list adapter calling Volley

```
public class MyList extends ArrayAdapter<>  {

// ....

VolleyClass vc = new VolleyClass(getContext());
vc.runVolley();

// ...

}
```

But I don't want to instantiate another request queue in every iteration of the list adapter.

So in VolleyClass I add this method

```
/**
 * @return The Volley Request queue, the queue will be created if it is null
 */
public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    // lazy initialize the request queue, the queue instance will be
    // created when it is accessed for the first time
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    }

    return mRequestQueue;
}
```

But since I am making a new instance of VolleyClass in the list adapter, I still always make a new instance of the Request queue.

How do I maintain one instance of the Request queue across my entire application using Java language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `mRequestQueue` static.
Like this,

```
public static RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

public static RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    }
    return mRequestQueue;
}
```

In Java, if you make a variable static, only one instance of that variable can be existed in the memory no matter how many objects you create. And all the objects will share that single instance.

Read more about singletons [here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073352/core-java/simply-singleton.html).